# How to remove Flutter TabBar left padding when isScrollable is true

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an annoying left space on my TabBar in my Flutter app which for some reason I cannot seem to get rid of it,

[image: screenshot]

I have tried padding, labelPadding, all seem not to work, see my code

```
TabBar(
  controller: _tabController,
  isScrollable: true,
  tabs: [
    const Tab(text: 'Info'),
    const Tab(text: 'Products'),
    const Tab(text: 'Browse'),
    const Tab(text: 'Queries'),
    const Tab(text: 'Activities'),
    const Tab(text: 'Staffs'),
  ],
)
```

If I remove the `isScrollable` flag, the space dissapears, how do I get rid of the space/padding, thanks.

Comment: There will be padding for label and indicator. 

Set it to zero by

                                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this attribute in Tabbar :

```
TabBar(
controller: _tabController,
tabAlignment: TabAlignment.center, // add this line 
isScrollable: true,
tabs: [
const Tab(text: 'Info'),
const Tab(text: 'Products'),
const Tab(text: 'Browse'),
const Tab(text: 'Queries'),
const Tab(text: 'Activities'),
const Tab(text: 'Staffs'),
],
)
```